# Access Object values using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

How to get access to "AddressPrefixes" value from below output (Azure Virtual Network info)?

I tried another way which is working - down below - I don't know how to format the output (e.g., remove [,",]) - I want only value 10.0.0.0/16

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
write-host $vnet.AddressSpaceText
```

> ```
> {
>   "AddressPrefixes": [
>     "10.0.0.0/16"
>   ]
> }
> ```

//Working:

```
write-host $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixesText
```

> ```
> [
>   "10.0.0.0/16"
> ]
> ```

Comment: Try `$vnet.AddressSpaceText.AddressPrefixes[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the AddressSpace property. AddressSpace**Text** returns JSON

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
write-host $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes
```

Because AddressPrefixesText returns JSON. So you could as well do:

```
write-host $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixesText | ConvertFrom-Json
```

But you shouldn't, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the PowerShell script:

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes
```

And the screenshot of the result here:

[image]

And the PowerShell command [`Get-AzVirtualNetwork`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azvirtualnetwork?view=azps-1.0.0) is used to get all the Vnet in the subscription if it does not have any more parameters. So if you just want to get a particular Vnet you can use the parameters that Vnet name `-Name` and resource group name `-ResourceGroupName`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Charles suggestion is working fine for me: $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes

Comment: @Rauf Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can mark me.